# Separating boundaries from WatershedComponents

Tags: image-processing, segmentation

I am trying to look for local minimum on the boundaries between watershed regions.

Typically the boundaries are not connected and spanning across the whole image so it is possible to do it through

```
MorphologicalComponents[
  1 - ImageData[Binarize[Colorize[WatershedComponents[image]], 0.1]]
]
```

The problem is when there are more than two watershed components are intersecting at a point and the boundary collides. The boundaries will then considered as one entity. This is illustrated as the green line in the picture where the watershed components are treated as the foregrounds.

[image: boundary merged]

Is there an efficient way to get unique pixels corresponding to the boundaries between two watershed components?

Here is the corresponding figure the watershed `image` is obtained by taking `Blur[input,{19.7002,10}]`.
[image: input]

**Possible Solution**

I worked them out and found some possible solution:

1. Get the watershed array using options that let the boundary be the foreground.

   ```
   wreg = WatershedComponents[image];
   ```
2. Get the positions of all foreground cell.

   ```
   linepos = Position[wreg, v_ /; v == 0];
   ```
3. For each foreground location get the list of unique surrounding watershed regions.

   ```
   surroundIndices[{i_, j_}, {dim1_, dim2_}] := Module[{
      ilist = Select[{i - 1, i, i + 1}, # > 0 && # <= dim1 &],
      jlist = Select[{j - 1, j, j + 1}, # > 0 && # <= dim2 &]
     },
     DeleteCases[Tuples[{ilist, jlist}], {i, j}]
   ];

   lineneighbor =
     Sort[DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates[Extract[wreg, #]], 0]] & /@
       (surroundIndices[#, Dimensions@wreg] & /@ (linePos));
   ```
4. Store the unique list of these identifiers and assign each foreground cell to the unique identifier. Note that we only care about the foreground cell with two neighboring region. A cell with 3 or 4 neighboring region will be labeled as -1

   ```
   neighborid = Select[DeleteDuplicates[lineneighbor], Length[#] == 2 &];
   lineid     = Replace[
     (lineneighbor /. AssociationThread[neighborid -> Range[Length[neighborid]]]),
     neighbor_ /; Length[neighbor] != 0 -> -1, {1}];
   ```
5. Create the new `lines` image

   ```
   lines = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[wreg]];
   Do[
     lines[[linepos[[i, 1]], linepos[[i, 2]] - 1]] = lineid[[i]],
     {i, Length[lineid]}
   ];
   ```
6. *(Optional)* Merge lines if needed on the branching point.
   Noting that the watershed boundary output is always connected perpendicularly first (i.e. diagonal boundary cell is not the direct neighbor of a boundary cell), we can merge the top-bottom and left-right boundary labels surrounding the branch point.

   ```
   linepos = Position[lines, v_ /; v == -1];
   Do[
     Module[{nuy, nux, lidL, lidR, lidU, lidD, y, x},
       {y, x} = pos;
       {nuy, nux} = Dimensions[wreg];

       If[y > 1 && y < nuy,
        If[lines[[y - 1, x]] > 0 && lines[[y + 1, x]] > 0,
         lines = lines /. {lines[[y + 1, x]] -> lines[[y - 1, x]]};
         ]
        ];

       If[x > 1 && x < nux,
        If[lines[[y, x - 1]] > 0 && lines[[y, x + 1]] > 0,
         lines = lines /. {lines[[y, x - 1]] -> lines[[y, x + 1]]}
         ]
        ];
       ];
     , {pos, linepos}
   ];
   ```

This method gives what I want:
[image: desired output]

Comment: Could you figure some way to include a sample `image` for people to work on?  Would the minimum on such a watershed boundary be a saddle point?

Comment: Would the joined part belong to either, none, or both of the boundaries? If it should be assigned to one of the boundaries, how should that be determined?

Comment: I have added the image. I think in general the minimum on watershed boundary should be a saddle point otherwise it will be inside a watershed region.


The joint point can probably be on one of the boundary based on the shape of the intersecting point. However, it is least likely that the joint will be the location of local minimum along the line due to how watershed segmentation works.